# Best way to get LaTex output from tbl_summary object in gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to get a document publication-ready and am doing everything in LaTeX.  However, I just now noticed that `gtsummary` doesn't yet support LaTeX output for its tables.  I'm wondering what the best way is to nevertheless convert the HTML tables into LaTeX?

One idea is to a website like https://tableconvert.com/ and convert from HTML.

Two questions:

1. How do I actually output the raw HTML code from a `gt` object to do this?  R automatically formats the tbl_summary object, and I don't see any helper functions for getting the raw html.
2. Is there a better way to transform the tables to LaTeX for publications that require submissions in LaTex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends somewhat on whether you are using R markdown to create entire LaTeX documents, or whether you're grabbing the LaTeX code for a single table and adding it manually to a larger document.

R Markdown: {gtsummary} supports output to PDF/LaTeX via a few different engines--gt (although, technically still under development for LaTeX. for simple tables I have had no problems with gt and Latex working nicely together), flextable, huxtable, kable, and kableExtra. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/articles/rmarkdown.html Using one of these output options for the gtsummary table should work for you.

If you need to convert a single gtsummary table to LaTeX or HTML, you will first want to convert is to {gt} then use the functions `gt::as_latex()` or `gt::as_raw_html()`.  These will aid in getting the raw HTML or Latex code you're after.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

trial %>%
  select(age, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::as_latex()

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty,skip=1pt}
\begin{longtable}{lc}
\toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{N = 200}\textsuperscript{1} \\ 
\midrule
Age, yrs & 47 (38, 57) \\ 
Unknown & 11 \\ 
Chemotherapy Treatment &  \\ 
Drug A & 98 (49\%) \\ 
Drug B & 102 (51\%) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\vspace{-5mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\textsuperscript{1}Statistics presented: median (IQR); n (\%) \\ 
\end{minipage}
```

I hope this is close to what you need/are looking for! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you so much, again!  I'm getting the error: `Error in as_latex(.) : could not find function "as_latex"`  Is this function only available in the development version of gtsummary?

Comment: Oops, I left off an important piece ! gt::as_latex()

Comment: While the ``gt::as_latex`` function works but was not useful code for a long table the ``gt::as_raw_html()`` did the trick